# how to determine one month previous to variable date php

Tags: php, date

```
$fdomLastMonth  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of -1 month', 
$sDate));
$lDomLastMonth  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of -1 month', 
$eDate));
```

This obviously does not work. But I am trying to find an easy way to enter dates in (`$sDate`, `$eDate`) and look at the `- 1 month` from whatever that may be so I have a date range to query with.

Comment: What are the values of $sDate and $eDate?

Comment: could be any month. So I can look back a month from which ever dates are chosen. Could be 2018-05-01 , could be 2018-03-01. the variable there is what is throwing me off. -1 month from variable date. oh man...

Comment: `first day of last month` and `last day of last month`. Works with next month etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'first day of YYYY-MM-DD -1 month'` and `'last day of YYYY-MM-DD -1 month'` work just fine and are understood by the [relative](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) formats of the datetime parser

`YYYY-MM-DD -1 month` is parsed first then it takes the first (or last) day of the month for that parsed date.

Comment: so would that be written as  'first day of $sDate -1 month'

Comment: Assuming $sDate is a format that the parser understands like YYYY-MM-DD or MM/DD/YYYY then yes